# Spacing between equation number and its description in a custom listofequations page

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, tocloft

I'm currently in the process of writing my thesis and have been asked to have a list of equations are the start of write up similar to that of a list of figures or list of tables. When compiled, the latter numbers of the "equation numbers" overlaps with the first letter(s) of their respective descriptions. What I would like to do is set a distance like I did using LaTeX internal macros for list of figures and tables like I did in the following code.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}% 3em instead of 2.3em
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2em} 
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother
```

However, due to this not being a defined part of LaTeX's internal macros i'm unsure as to how to do a similar command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

\listofmyequations

\newpage

\chapter{1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg1}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law1}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg2}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law2}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg3}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law3}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg4}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law4}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg5}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law5}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg6}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law6}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg7}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law7}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg8}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law8}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg9}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law9}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Bragg10}
        n\lambda = 2d_{hk\ell} \: sin\theta
    \end{equation}
        \myequations{Bragg's Law10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `} \: sin\theta`, do consider writing `}\sin\theta`. Let yourself be impressed by how much better the equations look. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix consists of changing

```
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
```

to

```
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}\qquad #1}\par}
```

This should suffice unless you have more than 999 equations [!] in one or more of your thesis chapters...